# double pointers and 2d arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, double, 2d

I'm trying to access a 2D array using double pointer

```
int x[2][2] = {{10, 20},{30, 40}};
int *xp;
int **xpp;

printf ("%d  %d\n%d  %d\n", x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1][0], x[1][1]);
printf ("\n");

xp = *x;
printf ("%d  %d\n%d  %d\n", *xp, *(xp + 1), *(xp + 2), *(xp + 3));
printf ("\n");

xpp = (int**)x;
printf ("%d\n", **xpp);
```

What I get is:

> ```
> 10  20
> 30  40
>
> 10  20
> 30  40
>
> Segmentation fault
> ```

Question: How should I access the array using `xpp`?

Comment: Why the cast `(int**)` in `xpp = (int**)x;`?  The cast hints that code is doing something _I know better than you compiler, so do it and do not complain_.

Comment: Right. Without the cast I get "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type". What is the best way to access the array using xpp?

Comment: "best way to access the array using xpp" --> Do not use `int **xpp;` - it is not the right type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than ...

```
int x[2][2] = {{10, 20},{30, 40}};
int **xpp;
xpp = (int**)x;
```

... realize that `x` in the expression converts to a pointer the address of the first element.  The first element of `x` is `x[0]` which has a type of `int [2]`, so the type needed is `int (*)[2]` or [pointer to array 2 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*p%29%5B2%5D%3B).

```
int (*p)[2];
p = x;

printf ("%p\n", (void *) p);
printf ("%p\n", (void *) *p);
printf ("%d\n", **p);
printf ("%d %d %d %d\n", p[0][0], p[0][1], p[1][0], p[1][1]);
```

Output

```
0xffffcbd0 (sample)
0xffffcbd0 (sample)
10
10 20 30 40
```

---

Tip: avoid casting - it often hides weak programming.